# convert timeit output into seconds or minutes

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I achieve the time a program took to execute in python

```
%timeit sum([i for i in range(1000) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0])
```

For that I got this output:

```
172 µs ± 10.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

But I want the time in seconds or minutes?

How can I check time in seconds or minutes for this code:

```
k = 0
n = 1000
for i in range(1, n):
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        k += i
```

Comment: A `µs` is a microsecond, or one-millionth of a second. `172 µs` is `0.000172` seconds. Also, `sum(i for i in range(1000) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0)` Is closer to your multi-line example.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I just wanted to know other ways to view the seconds/minutes directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `timeit` module:

```
import timeit
n= number of times
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: sum([i for i in range(1000) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0]),number=n))
```

Comment: I don't know it's just me but it's taking a lot of time. I executed it but still no output.

Comment: @user456 Because it executes 10000 times so maybe you should set the times you want, i'lle edit

Comment: @user456 Edited mine

Comment: @user456 Lesser the faster